# How to put a JButton inside a JTextField (Java)?

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield, jfilechooser

I would like to have a JButton (with a folder icon image) inside a JTextField, like over on the far right of the JTextField, so that when clicked, the button opens up a JFileChooser, and when a file is selected, the path to the file appears inside the JTextField.

I have made this code, but nothing shows up.

```
public class TextFieldChooser extends JTextField {

    public ImageIcon folderIcon;
    public JButton btnFolder;

    public TextFieldChooser(int columns) {
        super(columns);
        btnFolder = new JButton();
        folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/folder_find.png"));
        btnFolder.setIcon(folderIcon);
        this.add(btnFolder);

    }
}
```

Comment: "Favor object composition over class inheritance."—Erich Gamma http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on what Shakedown suggested, I think you can get the desired effect relatively easily. What you do is have a `JPanel` that contains both the text area and, beside it, the button. Next, set the text field to not draw any borders and give the `JPanel` a bevel border. Now it will look like the button is inside the text area. It might take some fine tuning, but it should work.

Comment: OK, that worked. Good thinking, and if this is what Shakedown originally intended to mean, then +1 to him too.

Comment: And here is a screen shot of my new component panel.

http://screencast.com/t/MDdiMTM0MTA

Answer (score 6):

You may find the [Component Border](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) helpfull. It allows you to display a button in the text field by using the Border API.

Comment: +1 In addition to the novel API, this is also a useful exposition on fine-tuning the conventional approach.

Comment: Sweet, this is great. The border I originally set on the JPanel worked good on Mac and Windows, but on Linux, the border failed. May be this will work better.

Answer (score 4):

You <strike>can't</strike> *don't want to* put a button in a text field. You need to break out your intent into several components - 3, in fact.

First you're going to need a parent container, or something that will contain both your text field and also the button; a `JPanel` should suffice.

Then you need your real components, and by real I mean the ones that actually do something. These are your `JTextField` and `JButton` - go ahead and add these to the `JPanel`. In order to add them and have them appear how you want (with the button in the corner), you're going to need to specify a layout for your `JPanel`. This layout will define where added components go (visually) inside the `JPanel`.

Now that you've added those things into your `JPanel`, you can work only with your `JPanel` instead of thinking in terms of the contained `JTextField` and `JButton`.

Comment: Take a look at this screenshot, this program was written in Delphi, and I am remaking it in Java. Delphi obviously had a component that meets this need. Why can't Java?

http://screencast.com/t/OTNhOTA2ZGY

Comment: You _can_ put a button in a text field; it's just awkward to render correctly.

Comment: Actually you could probably set the border to 0 and just have both right next to each other making it look like one is inside of the other

Comment: @TheLQ: Exactly. `JPanel` is explicitly intended as "a generic lightweight container."

Answer (score 2):

Because Pyrite has not posted his final solution, here is mine:

```
my_button = new JButton("x");
JFormattedTextField my_textfield = new JFormattedTextField("Nr.");
my_textfield.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

JPanel textfield_with_button = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
Border lowered_bevelborder = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
textfield_with_button.setBorder(lowered_bevelborder);

textfield_with_button.add(my_textfield);
textfield_with_button.add(my_button);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I probably think you got your answer, but for others who want to do this easily, cuz I think the other answers are a bit too complicated.
So, what you need to do is, when you create the `JTextField` you create the `JButton` as well. Well see the code for yourself:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBounds(50, 5, 50, 25);
button.setBackground(Color.black);
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 35);
textField.setBackground(Color.white);
textField.add(button);
```

And its that easy, I used `setBounds()` on the button cuz I can place it anywhere I want, as for the textField you can use a frame/panel layout aswell, but this was for just demonstrating how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in 2024. Essentially you put a JButton and JTextField inside of a JPanel with BoxLayout. Then you set the size of the JTextfield to fill up the rest of the JPanel.

```java
    private JPanel createButtonAndTextFieldCombo(JButton button, JTextField textField) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, 0));
        panel.setBackground(textField.getBackground());
        panel.setBorder(textField.getBorder());
        textField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
        textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }
```