# How to add eye symbol in JPasswordField?

Tags: java, swing

How can I add an eye symbol in my java application using java swing?

Comment: [How to put a JButton inside a JTextField (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671461/how-to-put-a-jbutton-inside-a-jtextfield-java) and you should look at [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this several ways. In the below code, I create a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html) which contains a [JPasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) and a [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) which displays an "eye" icon. I remove the [border](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) from the `JPasswordField`. (Note that, by default, a `JLabel` does not have a border.) And I add a border to the `JPanel` that makes it look like a single, text field. I got that idea from the accepted answer to [How to put a JButton inside a JTextField (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671461/how-to-put-a-jbutton-inside-a-jtextfield-java). Finally, I add a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to the `JLabel`. When the mouse pointer is inside the `JLabel`, the text in the `JPasswordField` is readable and when the mouse pointer is not inside the `JLabel`, the text in the `JPasswordField` is displayed as a string of asterisk characters, i.e. `*`.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class PassWord extends MouseAdapter {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        passwordField.setEchoChar('\u0000');
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createEye(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createEye() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(15);
        passwordField.setBorder(null);
        panel.add(passwordField);
        URL location = getClass().getResource("eye_show_password.png");
        Icon ico = new ImageIcon(location);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(ico);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(passwordField.getBackground());
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        panel.add(label);
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        container.add(panel);
        return container;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new PassWord().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! you answer helped me to develop my project further :)